# Драйвер для дешифрования устройства

Tags: linux, c, криптография, драйвер

Возникла задача создать минимальный образ, зашифровать его простейшим способом и написать драйвер, который будет дешифровать его «на лету».

Создаю образ:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=myFS bs=1024 count=60
mkfs.ext2 myFS
```

Шифрую XOR-ом:

```
int main()
{
    std::fstream streamIn;
    std::fstream streamOut;

    const char key = 0b00001111;

    streamIn.open("myFS", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in);
    streamOut.open("newFS", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::out);

    char b;
    while (streamIn.read(&b, 1))
    {
        b ^= key;
        streamOut.write(&b, 1);
    }

    streamIn.close();
    streamOut.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Далее пишу драйвер. Он основан на device-mapper target-е, и основная функция обработки запросов имеет следующий прототип:

```
static int sddm_target_map(struct dm_target *ti, struct bio *bio);
```

То есть я имею в своём распоряжении структуру bio, в которой, как мне это видится, я должен дешифровать все байты. Хороших примеров я не нашёл. Сделал так:

```
struct bio_vec vec;
struct bvec_iter it;
unsigned int len;
char *addr;
unsigned int i;

bio_for_each_segment(vec, bio, it)
{
    len = vec.bv_len;
    addr = (char*)(page_address(vec.bv_page) + vec.bv_offset);

    for (i = 0; i != len; ++i)
    {
        *(addr+i) ^= 0b00001111;
    }
}
```

Очевидно, что не всё так просто. При попытке монтирования моего устройства получаю следующее:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/mydevice
```

Видел ещё такой вариант:

```
bio_for_each_segment(vec, bio, it)
{
    len = vec.bv_len;
    addr = kmap_atomic(vec.bv_page);
    pointer = (char *)(addr + vec.bv_offset);

    for (i = 0; i != len; ++i)
    {
        *(pointer+i) ^= 0b00001111;
    }

    kunmap_atomic(addr);
}
```

Но и он выдаёт ту же ошибку.

Подскажите, как правильно реализовать задуманное! Спасибо!

---

**UPDATE**

Поисследовал, какие данные содержатся в этих bio. Во-первых, вывел номер читаемого сектора:

```
bio_for_each_segment(vec, bio, it)
{
    // ...
    printk(KERN_CRIT "Sector: %lu\n", it.bi_sector);
    // ...
}
```

Что интересно, когда читаю нормальный образ, выводится:

```
0, 24, 8, 56, 8, 0, 24, 56
```

А если зашифрованный, то:

```
0, 24, 8, 56, 64, 16, 32, 8, 0, 24, 56, 64, 16, 32
```

То есть как будто бы в первых четырёх секторах зашифрованного образа (0, 24, 8, 56) содержится то, что заставляет читать какие-то три непонятных сектора (64, 16, 32).

Во-вторых, попробовал вывести содержимое bio целиком. Сделал так:

```
char *output;
char *temp;
unsigned int j;
// .....

bio_for_each_segment(vec, bio, it)
{
    len = vec.bv_len;
    addr = (char*)(page_address(vec.bv_page) + vec.bv_offset);

    output = (char*)kmallok(15000, GFP_KERNEL);
    output[0] = '\0';

    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i != len; ++i)
    {
        temp = (char*)kmallok(10, GFP_KERNEL);

        //*(addr+i) ^= 0b00001111;

        itoa(((unsigned short)(*(addr + i))) & 0x00FF, temp, 16);
        strcat(output, " ");
        strcat(output, temp);
        // Вывожу по кускам, потому что журнал урезает сообщение
        if (++j == 256)
        {
            j = 0;
            printk(KERN_CRIT, output);
            output[0] = '\0';
        }
        kfree(temp);
    }

    printk(KERN_CRIT, output);
    kfree(output);
}
```

Имплементацию itoa взял [здесь](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-itoa/). Там используется функция reverse, её взял [здесь](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdlib.h/itoa).

В итоге в этих первых четырёх запросах выводятся **исключительно нули**! Причём как в нормальном образе, так и в зашифрованном. Что же заставляет его читать именно эти сектора...

---

**UPDATE**

Только что попробовал запустить нешифрованный образ под этим драйвером - нормально монтируется. То есть сейчас драйвер в принципе ничего не делает.

Comment: >bad superblock - возможно, superblock не должен шифроваться

Comment: @AlexanderZonov ошибка выводится другая: mount /dev/mapper/mydevice on /mnt failed: Structure needs cleaning. Да и по всей видимости ошибка глубже. Только что попробовал под этим же драйвером поработать с нешифрованным устройством (почему я не попробовал это сделать раньше?) - нормально монтируется. То есть сейчас драйвер в принципе ничего не делает

Comment: Посмотрите тут: (http://support.qbpro.ru/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B2_Linux)
-- простите, что мешает в вашем драйвере вшить пароль используя стандартные возможности?

Comment: @Valery под стандартными возможностями Вы имеете ввиду cryptsetup и т.д.? Драйвер будет специфичным, так что приходится писать руками. На самом деле я добился результата, взяв за основу исходники TrueCrypt. Просто ещё не разобрался как следует, чтобы написать ответ

Comment: Во общем да. Просто можно было бы использовать работу модуля криптования а уж реализацию делать как угодно.. :-)

Comment: комментарий написать не могу, в силу репутации. возможно дело в типе массива addr и он не верно xor'ится. попробуйте использовать либо unsigned char, либо byte.

Comment: 1. уже можешь. 2. вопросу сто лет ;), надо сделать так чтоб больше другим, чем автору было полезно. Впрочем отвечать можно и надо на любые вопросы не смотря на их "возраст"

Comment: Да, я тоже бы предложил по другому определить массив, это лучше для "raw" буфера: unsigned char* addr;